# How may I place number '(2)' on number '(3)'?

Tags: equations, numbering

Here it is placed on `(\alpha).`

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage{mathtools}


\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
(1).\,(\alpha)&& a^m \times a^n&=a^{m + n},&\\
\makebox[0pt]{and generally}&&
a^m \times a^n \times a^p \times \dotsm&= a^{m + n + p + \dotsb}&\\
(\beta)&& \frac{a^{m}}{a^{n}}&= a^{m-n}\,\text{if}\; m>n,&\\
\makebox[0pt]{}&&
&=\frac{1}{a^{n-m}}\,\text{if}\; m<n.&\\
(2).&&(a^m)^{n}&=a^{mn}=(a^{n})^{m}.&\\
(3).\,(\alpha)&&(ab)^{m}&=a^{m}b^{m},&\\
\makebox[0pt]{and generally}&&
(abc\dotsm)^{m}&=a^{m}\times b^{m}\times c^{m}\times \dotsm&\\
(\beta)&& \Big(\frac{a}{b}\Big)^{m}&=\frac{a^{m}}{b^{m}}.
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just add `\phantom{\,(\alpha)}` after `(2).`

Comment: It  worked perfectly. Thank you very much, Guido!

Comment: A picture would vastly improve the reuseability of this question. A current, and desired output

Comment: How may I attach an image to my coding mentioned above? I do not know that.

Comment: why are you numbering the equations by hand `(1)` etc? you should almost never need to do that. LaTeX has extensive facilities for numbering and cross referencing.

Comment: to upload a picture use the image button in the editor (or just type control G) which starts an upload dialog.

Comment: To David, I must study the given facilities on numbering and cross-referencing. I think ShareLaTex has provided the latter in detail. Thank you for sharing your knowledge, David!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure of what you want to achieve, but this should be it: it's just using the second column (with left alignment) instead of the first for the material that should be at the left margin. Don't forget it's `\makebox[0pt][l]{...}` or TeX would use centering in the available space, surely not what you want.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
&(1).\,(\alpha)& a^m \times a^n&=a^{m + n},&\\
&\makebox[0pt][l]{and generally}&
a^m \times a^n \times a^p \times \dotsm&= a^{m + n + p + \dotsb}&\\
&(\beta)& \frac{a^{m}}{a^{n}}&= a^{m-n}\,\text{if}\; m>n,&\\
& &
&=\frac{1}{a^{n-m}}\,\text{if}\; m<n.&\\
&(2).&(a^m)^{n}&=a^{mn}=(a^{n})^{m}.&\\
&(3).\,(\alpha)&(ab)^{m}&=a^{m}b^{m},&\\
&\makebox[0pt][l]{and generally}&
(abc\dotsm)^{m}&=a^{m}\times b^{m}\times c^{m}\times \dotsm&\\
&(\beta)& \Big(\frac{a}{b}\Big)^{m}&=\frac{a^{m}}{b^{m}}.
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: \makebox[0pt]{...} is what I used. I did not know until now that it could make a significant difference. Thank you for the improvement you have made. Could you please tell me how you placed the image at the end of your coding? (The image placed above)